# how to recognize a face of the same person in different situations

Tags: ros, face-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to develop the program that will recognize a person every times he sees the robot and the robot greets him/her if he recognize them else the robot should ask his/her  name and save it for next time..

i know this has been developed earlier like in qbo but i also want to implement it so i can work on the enhancement.

please provide any help of what to do

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49498/how-to-recognize-a-face-of-the-same-person-in-different-situations/) by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't implemented face recognition myself, but if/when I get to that point, I would start my research here:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition

---

Originally posted by [jkp](https://answers.ros.org/users/3397/jkp/) with karma: 43 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1